# Exporting a shape made out of quads results in hexagons in obj file

Tags: export, geometry

I made some sort of furniture by taking the default cube and insetting some parts of it and splitting(subdividing) it here and there. Then I add a bevel modifier with 1 segment.

A view of the model, with modifier applied (as you can see there are only quads here):
[image: model view]

I export it as obj, the only box I have checked is "apply modifiers".
In the exported obj you will find a couple of faces which have 6 vertices, which shouldn't happen. Why does it and how do I fix it? It's important that this mesh gets exported as an obj with only quads/bilinear patches

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any way of looking at an .obj file to see where your problem appears, but you have two spurious vertices on the edges of the bottom face which you can see in Blender if you turn off the bevel modifier. Not sure whether deleting those would sort your problem?

[image]

Comment: I have deleted those vertices but the problem persists. You can open a .obj file with a simple text editor like notepad and then look for "f" (face) with 6 numbers, something like `f 11 45 24 74 21 10`
The numbers refer to which vertices the face connects.

Comment: Ah ok. Filed for future reference in case I ever need to unpick one! Glad to see you've sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why it happes. The front/back edges connected to these 6 vertices:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For educational purposes(2.79).

Just enable the **Edit Tool 2** addon to see what is happening to your meshes.

You will get a **Face Info / Select** panel where you can see and select Ngons, Quads and Tris.

I always use it to check and fix my models before export them to an AR app.

[image]